# Asp.net Web Api NuGet Packages

Tags: asp.net-web-api, nuget

I've created a new Web Api project in Visual Studio 2012 and I've realised that it is created with a bunch of NuGet packages... do I really need all of these packages? Can I remove some of them?
This is the list of packages installed:

```
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.8.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.8.24" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.10.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core" version="1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.LocalDB" version="1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="2.0.20715.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax" version="2.0.30116.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="2.0.30116.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.11" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, no you don't.  When you choose the Web Api template in VS it assumes a lot of the packages (and folders) you will need.  I usually start with an empty asp.net application and just use NuGet to add the packages I need.  This is what mine looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.5" targetFramework="net451" />
</packages>
```